# Combining multiple "COUNTIF" formula into one statement

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif, ifs

## Situation:

I want to search for a range of specific column in order to check whether it contains multiple specific strings or not. If selected strings found, it will returns a string based on the following conditions.

```
contain "#ERROR!" -> return "Partly Abnormal"

contain "#N/A" -> return "Abnormal"

contain "#N/A" and "#ERROR!" -> return "Abnormal"

No above strings -> return "Normal"
```

## Problem:

For this purpose, I typed the following formula but I tried several hours and still have no idea how to combine both into one. Your help is high appreciated, thank you!

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A,"#N/A"),"Abnormal","Normal")

=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A,"#ERROR!"),"Partly Abnormal","Normal")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use [IFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en) instead of `IF`

This allows you to combine several conditions in one.

Mind: `IFS` does not allow to specify a default condition if non of the specified strings are found, but you can do it with a atrick by specifying as the last condition `true`:

```
=IFS(COUNTIF(A2:A,"#N/A"),"Abnormal", COUNTIF(A2:A,"#ERROR!"),"Partly Abnormal", true, "Normal")
```

Answer (score 0):

nested `IF`

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A,"#N/A"), "Abnormal",
 IF(COUNTIF(A2:A,"#ERROR!"), "Partly Abnormal", "Normal"))
```

[image: 0]